# Python import variable from function in another script

Tags: python, tkinter, import

I am working on a project where I need to import variable itemLink from one file to another. This variable consists of some predefined strings and some that you have to enter in GUI. All code works, but I can't figure out how to solve this import issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Main program (GUI)

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import sys
import subprocess



def generate():
    global itemLink
    itemLink = "predefined_text" + itemName.get() + "predefined_tex" + itemSize.get()
    subprocess.Popen("Nastavitve.py 1", shell=True)

def GUI_start():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Test")

    Label(window, text="Item name").grid(row=0)
    Label(window, text="Size").grid(row=1)

    global itemName
    global itemSize

    itemName = Entry(window)
    itemSize = Entry(window)

    itemName.grid(row=0, column=1)
    itemSize.grid(row=1, column=1)

    button = Button(window, text="Generate link", fg="red",command=generate)
    button.grid(row=0, column=2)


    window.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI_start()
```

Second program (stores necessary data)

```
from UI import itemLink
keys = {
    "link": itemLink,
    "email": "your acount email",
    "password": "password"
}

def printLink():
    print(itemLink)
    print("end")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    printLink()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution it probably isn't the best so if anyone has any recommendations please write them below. Now I have to start Settings which automatically opens UI when it imports it after clicking the button it prints the link in the console as intended. Preferably I would like it the other way around so that the UI could open Settings and store variables in there.

Settings

```
from UI import itemName, itemSize

itemLink = "predefined" + itemName.get() + "predefined" + itemSize.get()

print(itemLink)
print("end")

keys = {
    "link": itemLink,
    "email": "your acount email",
    "password": "password"
}
```

UI

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import sys
import subprocess

def generate():
    #subprocess.Popen("Nastavitve.py 1", shell=True)
    import Settings
    time.sleep(0.1)

window = Tk()
window.title("SHOP BOT")
window.configure(background="black")

Label(window, text="Item name").grid(row=0)
Label(window, text="Size").grid(row=1)

global itemName
global itemSize

itemName = Entry(window)
itemSize = Entry(window)

itemName.grid(row=0, column=1)
itemSize.grid(row=1, column=1)

button = Button(window, text="Generate link", fg="red",command=generate)
button.grid(row=0, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```